# FabricJS resizing groups and objects in them

Tags: fabricjs

I need to programmaticaly resize a group and it's contained elements on a fabric canvas.

By default, fabric applies scaling to objects.  I can get around this easily enough by using the scalex & scaley to calculate the new height and width then I set them back to 1.  This works fine for the group but I cant figure out how to set the new size for the objects contained in this group.

Eg.  Before resize:
[image: Before resize]
After resize:

[image: After resize]

My (typescript) code is like:

```
redraw() {

  this.shapeGroup.set({
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    left: this.shape.origin.x,
    top: this.shape.origin.y,
    width: this.shape.extent.width + this.shape.line.lineWidth,
    height: this.shape.extent.height + this.shape.line.lineWidth,
    dirty: true
  });
  // const ac = this.shapeGroup.calcCoords();

  this.shapeElement.set({
    rx: this.shape.cornerRadius,
    ry: this.shape.cornerRadius,
    width: this.shape.extent.width,
    height: this.shape.extent.height,
    dirty: true
  });
  // this.shapeElement.setCoords(ac);

  if (this.shape.text) {
    this.textElement.set({
      width: this.shapeElement.width - (this.cornerRadius * 2),
      height: this.shapeElement.height - (this.cornerRadius * 2)
    });
  }

  this.canvas.fabric.renderAll();
}
```

(this.shape is the underlying model of the object which is represented by 1 or more fabric objects in a group).

Has anyone done anything like this with success?

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar code to resize the group items, so maybe this can lead you to a solution.

```
canvas.setActiveGroup(this.shapeGroup.setCoords());
var objs = canvas.getActiveGroup().getObjects();
for(i in objs){
    objs[i].set({
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I already have a reference to the objects in the group.  Setting the top, left is the problem.  Their current values a negative and changing them places the object well outside the group boundary.